# C++ and SQLite compilation error: "undefined reference to `sqlite3_open"

Tags: c++, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to get started with the SQLite on Eclipse CDT on Windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sqlite3/sqlite3.h"

int main(){
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *res;

    const char *errMSG;
    const char *tail;

    int error = sqlite3_open("test.db",&db);
    if (error){
        std::cout << "Could not open db." << std::endl;
        sqlite3_close(db);
        //system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    std::string query = "SELECT * FROM test";

    error = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), query.length(), &res, &tail);

    if (error != SQLITE_OK){
        std::cout << "Could not prepare SQL" << std::endl;
        sqlite3_close(db);
        //system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    while (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW){
        std::cout << "Name: " << sqlite3_column_text(res,0) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "NUmber: " << sqlite3_column_text(res,1) << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(res);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the line that compiles the code:
 `g++ "-LD:\SQLite3\lib" -o sqliteTest00.exe main.o -lsqlite3`  which include the lsqlite3. But when I build the project I will get the  `undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open"`  as well for  `'sqlite3_close'`  and  `'sqlite3_prepare_v2'`  and the rest of  `'sqlite3_`  commands. Any idea what is the problem with this file or linker?

Comment: Is that message from the compiler or the linker?

Comment: @HotLicks I got it from the Eclipse console.

Comment: No problem in Visual Studio though

Comment: Is the message from the compiler or the linker??

Comment: @HotLicks It is from the compiler